# Extract each word from a String and compare frequency

Tags: java, string

I have a `String str = "28catsdogsbuscatsdogshomebike";` I have to extract each and every word from String and count frequency for each word. String can have a number `0<n<20` and there is no `whitespace` b/w words.

I tried solutions like extracting each word from a String but solution is not working b'coz String do not contain any whitespace.

Comment: Since the string does not contain white space what is considered as a word?

Comment: Immediately there is a problem here, because we may not even be able to discern where a word begins and ends.  What about the string `dumbbellfloormat`?  Is this two words, `dumbbell` and `floormat`, or four words `dumb` `bell` `floor` `mat` ?

Comment: how are you going to differentiate between "dogs" and "home" and "dogshome" and "home" and "bike" and "homebike"?

Comment: May ask the output of String after extract
*28catsdogsbuscatsdogshomebike* = **28  catsdogs bus catsdogs homebike** OR **28 cats dogs bus cats dogs homebike** OR another ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  can be try like search engine works like when you type `dum` its gives you `dumb` and we can count `dumb` and so on

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to do,provided you have a dictionary read from a file to check the word exists after reading upto certain chars,and match it with dictionary,or provide spaces between input words

**try-with-resources**

```
 String[] words;

 try
        {
            FileReader file_reader = new FileReader("words.txt");
            BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader(file_reader);

            String word;
            while((word = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                words[i] = word;
                i++;
            }

            buffered_reader.close();
        }
```

use this to compare formed word array with the string you can make with character as an iteration till you get meaningful words,then it is possible to count words.

```
       int testMeaningfulWords(String stringformed){ 
        if(words.contains(stringformed)){
          return 1;
        }
}
```

**read character by character from a string**

```
string s="";
for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
      if(i==0)
      {
        s=str.charAt(i);
       }
     else{
       s=s+str.charAt(i);
       }
       int k=testMeaningfulWords(s);
       if(k==1)
       {
       s="";
        }
}
```

Comment: Someone who gives downvote is unreasonable. Please, explain what's  wrong before giving downvote

Answer (score 0):

Since string does not contains `white spaces` so concept of `words` virtually do not exists. You have to manually create words dictionary in your memory model say `wordsDictionary`  here is sample

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

 public class Words {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "28catsdogsbuscatsdogshomebike";
    String str1 = "dogshomebike";
    extractWords(str);
    System.out.println("=========");
    extractWords(str1);
}

/**
 * @param str
 */
private static void extractWords(String str) {
    String wordsDictionary []= {"dog","cat","bus","home","bike"};
    Map<String,Integer> matchingStr = new HashMap<String ,Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < wordsDictionary.length; i++) {
        String string = wordsDictionary[i];
        int count = StringUtils.countMatches(str, string);
        matchingStr.put(string, count);
    }
    for (String string : matchingStr.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(string + "  frequency "+matchingStr.get(string));
    }

  }

 }
```